# is it a conflict? about c++ auto

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ primer 5 I see the code:

```
const int a = 40;
auto &b = a;
```

The compiler can deduce `b` with type: `const int &`.
I think this is reasonable as a is a `const int` and if b has type `int &` them we can change the value of a `const int`, which is illegal.

However, the book said that the auto deduction will omit the top level const, with this rule, in the code: `auto &b = a;` the a only has type int, them we can defer that the b has type `int &`, which conflicts that b has type `const int &`.

Another question is the code:

```
auto &a = 8;
```

The compiler can't deduce that a has type `const int &` directly while in the code:

```
const int a = 40;
auto &b = a;
```

the compiler can. Why the difference?

Comment: It is unclear what is it you are asking? Please spell out a concrete, specific question that needs to be answered.

Comment: I think that word `defer` should be replaced with `infer`.

Comment: @myaut Not `infer`, `deduce`.

Comment: @Barry: they are very close. I.e. wikipedia: `Type inference is the ability to automatically deduce...` Also, [infer joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2pzv2e/in_c14_you_just_write_auto_autoauto_auto_auto_the/)

Comment: thanks，sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` deduction, with a few minor exceptions, works exactly the same way as normal template deduction. Say we have a function:

```
template <class T> void foo(T& param);

const int a = 40;
foo(a);
```

In this example, `T` would deduce to `const int` and the type of `param` would be `const int&`. By the same reasoning, `auto& b = a;` gives you a reference to `const int`.

However, `foo(8)` will not compile. `T&` can only bind to an lvalue, and `8` is not an lvalue. So that's ill-formed. Similarly, `auto& a = 8;` is ill-formed.

Comment: Few minor exceptions?

Comment: @carry Because `T const&` *can* bind to rvalues. `T&` can't. Same way with templates.

Comment: @GillBates Having to do with `initializer_list`.

Comment: @Barry so when deducing auto，should i still omit the top level const at first?

Comment: @Barry another question, about auto, in the code: `const int a = 0; auto b = a;` the b will be deduced to have type int , ignoring the top level const, is it the same in template?

Comment: @rengar b will has int type (no top level const), [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)